# Updating a non-Microsoft DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, powershell, .net

I need some PowerShell tool or .NET library or that uses the DNS protocol directly, as I need to perform dynamic updates on a non-Microsoft DNS, while WMI and DNS cmdlets only work for MicroSoft DNS servers.

I've tried the [ARSoft.Tools.Net library](https://arsofttoolsnet.codeplex.com/), but I always get a FormatError return code (see example below).

Are there any other tools available?

```
using ARSoft.Tools.Net;
using ARSoft.Tools.Net.Dns;
using ARSoft.Tools.Net.Dns.DynamicUpdate;
using System;
using System.Net;

class Program {

    static void TestUpdateAdd(IPAddress dnsServerIP,
                              DomainName updateZoneName,
                              DomainName newRecordName,
                              IPAddress newRecordIPAddress,
                              DomainName tsigName,
                              byte[] tsigKey) {

        var client = new DnsClient(dnsServerIP, 150000);
        client.IsUdpEnabled = false;

        var msg = new DnsUpdateMessage { ZoneName = updateZoneName };

        msg.Updates.Add(
            new AddRecordUpdate(
                new ARecord(newRecordName, 86400, newRecordIPAddress)));

        msg.TSigOptions = new TSigRecord(tsigName, TSigAlgorithm.Md5, DateTime.Now, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5),
            msg.TransactionID, ReturnCode.NoError, null, tsigKey);

        DnsUpdateMessage dnsResult = client.SendUpdate(msg);
        if (dnsResult == null) {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed sending message");
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine(dnsResult.ReturnCode); // FormatError
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From having a quick look my impression is that the current ARSoft.Tools.Net versions (tried 2.2.4 and a few spot checks of versions before it) appear to be bugged with regards to TSIG signing.
There appears to be an error causing the TTL is included twice in the `TSIG` record, which obviously offsets everything after, completely breaking any parsing of the record.

If you were to take an old version, like 1.8.2, essentially the same code that you have in the question does work just fine (biggest difference is that it uses string in place of DomainName). That said, I have no idea if there are other issues with the older versions that could make this approach undesirable.

Some general notes regardless if you use this specific library or not:

- Your [*fudge*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2845#page-4) value (allowed time difference) is very low and may prove a problem even after resolving the main issue.
- You hardcoded the use of MD5. While [HMAC-MD5 is not directly affected by the currently known serious problems with MD5](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9336/is-hmac-md5-considered-secure-for-authenticating-encrypted-data), generally you would move on where you can (to eg HMAC-SHA256).

Comment: Fwiw, I filed a bug at https://arsofttoolsnet.codeplex.com/workitem/50